# Alternate for cgi-bin in python

Tags: python

I have to execute some os commands on linux system from windows system so I want to use python cgi scripting for this purpose.

But I don't have the access

1. for cgi-bin folder
2. to install any new packages
3. to edit httpd.conf file

Is there any alternate for cgi in python ?

Comment: You could write a XMLRPC server to wrap your os commands. Maybe overkill, but it is what I came up with.

Comment: WSGI? [`Flask`](http://flask.pocoo.org/) is pretty lightweight